# Sourcetree some local branches disappeared

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I opened Sourcetree today and for some reason I could not see Master and Hotfix branch and also bunch of my features I was working on were gone, it only shows 2 now, while yesterday there was like 8 of them.

So is there a way to find out which of these features are gone? They are in remote, but there is like 500 other branches and now I dont know what I was working on (some of them are months old). Is there a way to filter them somehow? They were not finished.

Also when I try to checkout master you can see the error in screenshot, saying its already there. Maybe its just hidden or something

[image]

Comment: Could it be that some of my files on my local hard drive are corrupted? My hdd is acting weird for some time, Im getting messages saying there are errors on my drive and some files became corrupted.

Comment: Maybe, you can try to clone the repo from remote in another folder

Comment: I cloned it and it appears to be working.

However is there a way how to get back my features I was working on?

Comment: If you’ve committed work, you can push to your remote and pull on the other computer.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue when working with a large number of branches. It seems there is a limit to the number of branches that SourceTree is able to manage. We had a couple hundred branches checked out, almost all of them local and not pushed to the origin. When a new branch was made by someone else, and the commit showed up in the timeline, a folder of a couple hundred hotfixes quit showing its branches. We tried updating SourceTree and rebooting, and even looked at doing a filesystem repair (which warned us it could take hours, so we didn't do it).

In the end, we zipped up the local repo, opened it up on another computer, and saw the same problem. We then opened the repo in GitKraken, and it showed all the branches like it should. So we deleted a branch, and then SourceTree started seeing all of the hotfix branches under the hotfixes folder again.

We decided to clean up old branches since we didn't need them anymore; the code had been merged into other branches and those were pushed to origin. But we now know that SourceTree has limitations that GitKraken does not.

Comment: Good to know, however that was not my problem. My ssd was just dying.